# Force image to a specific size if it is larger

Tags: html

I have an image I am displaying in a image tag:

These are thumbnails, but some are a little to wide so for those images I want to force the display to shrink them (even though the larger image is loaded).

How can i do this for images that are larger, while not expanding images that are smaller.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS properties max-width and max-height on images.

```
img {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

works great with all popular browsers, including IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a css class to only those images that exceed a given height or width, then set the height and width in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could just specify the **height** and **width** attribute of the <img> tag to a value that generally suits most of the images that you are likely to encounter.